# VirtualPathProvider won't see requests because * filetype handler not set on asp.net development server

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, virtualpathprovider

I am using a VirtualPathProvider to serve some resources from .dll's (plugins). In IIS one can change the filetype filter for the ASP.NET ISAPI filter to '*'. How can I do the same for the ASP.NET development server that comes with Visual Studio?

Cheers in advance!

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET deployment server can process all request (similar to ISAPI configuration on IIS6) if you add this to your web.config:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
```